# Issue with dynamic query and datepart SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm getting the error

> Invalid parameter 1 specified for dateadd.

when I try to execute the following dynamic parametrized query in SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @Interval nvarchar(5) = 'DAY'  
DECLARE @Increment int = 10
DECLARE @BaseDate date = getdate()
DECLARE @ResultDate date
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(2000)

SET @Query = 'SELECT @result = DATEADD(@Interval, @Increment, CAST(@BaseDate AS DATE))'    

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query,
           N'@result date OUTPUT, @Interval varchar(50), @Increment int, @BaseDate date',
           @Interval = @Interval, @Increment = @Increment, 
           @BaseDate = @BaseDate, @result = @ResultDate OUTPUT

SELECT @ResultDate
```

I've changed the `SET @Query` line to this one.

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT @result = DATEADD(' + @Interval +', @Increment, CAST(@BaseDate AS DATE))'
```

Although it works fine, I'm curious about why the first statement is causing the error in my dynamic SQL query?. Doesn't `sp_executesql` generate the same statement than the concatenated query one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way to think about parameterized dynamic sql is you can only use a parameter where you could if it were static SQL. `DATEADD` expects a special date part keyword (e.g. `day, hour, year`, etc), not a literal string, and not a variable. It's the same issue some people run into where they think they can parameterize something like a table name. The first statement fails because even in static sql, this is invalid:

```
declare @increment nvarchar(5) = 'day'

select dateadd(@increment, 1, getdate())
```

That's equivalent to

```
select dateadd('day', 1, getdate())
```

The second statement succeeds because you're concatenating the string "day" which gets evaluated to the *keyword*.

Comment: This is a good answer, but to add something... see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql where it says about the datepart argument "User-defined variable equivalents are not valid."

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the query (with `@Interval` expanded to its value) becomes this:

```
SELECT @result=DATEADD('DAY', @Increment, CAST(@BaseDate AS DATE))
```

and in the second query it becomes this:

```
SELECT @result=DATEADD(DAY, @Increment, CAST(@BaseDate AS DATE))
```

The first query is invalid because there the first parameter to DATEADD is a **string value**, where the compiler expects a **language keyword**, and those are not the same in SQL.

For more info, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql
Please note the line under *datepart* saying `User-defined variable equivalents are not valid`. In other words you can't put quotes around these "values", they are not strings but keywords, and they can not be put in variables.